# Assigning a specific function CALL to a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a function call with parameters stored all as a function.

I have simplified my code to show what i am trying to do, but its just the same with some changes for less confusion.

```js
function addNums(x,y) {
  var z = x + y;
  console.log(z);
}

var runFunction = 'addNums(12,6)'

runFunction;
```

Hopefully ive made it clear what i am trying to do here, I am not getting an error from the last line, it just doesnt run!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to execute the code contained in a string:

```js
function addNums(x,y) {
  var z = x + y;
  console.log(z);
}

var runFunction = 'addNums(12,6)'

eval(runFunction); // Here!
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function addNums(x, y) {
  const z = x + y;
  console.log(z);
}

const runFunction = () => addNums(12, 6);

runFunction();
```

This should work for you. As someone else mentioned you can use `eval` but you should generally avoid that since it can be dangerous.

Comment: how can it be dangerous ?

Comment: `var runFunction = 'addNums(someMaliciousCodeDisguisedAsaHarmlessString)'; eval(runFunction);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the call if you don't want to immediately invoke the function.

```js
    function addNums(x,y) {
      var z = x + y;
      console.log(z);
    }

    var runFunction = addNums.bind(this,12,6);

    runFunction();
```